# How to dynamically build class with bases of another class without knowing them?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this class:

```
class C(A,B):
    ....
    ....
    ....
```

I want to build a new class with the bases A,B , but i dont actually know which bases `C` has or how many.

Ive tried: `class D(C.__bases__):`

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
list() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
```

Now if I do: `class D(C.__bases__[0],C.__bases__[1])`,it works, but i need todo this without knowing how many bases are there.

Tried:

```
D(','.joing(C.__bases__)):
```

But this doesnt work as well

Comment: I strongly recommend to read more: [PythonProgramming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Metaclasses#Metaclasses) and [What is a metaclass in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a class with a dynamic set of bases, you'll have to use [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type):

```
def methodname1(self):
    pass

D = type('D', C.__bases__, {
    'attribute': 42,
    'methodname1': methodname1
})
```

`type()` takes the class name, a sequence of bases, and a dictionary of class attributes. These include all functions.

The above example is the equivalent of:

```
class D(A, B):
    attribute = 42

    def methodname1(self):
        pass
```

If `C` has a metaclass, you'd use that; if you are not sure if `C` has a metatype, use:

```
D = type(C)('D', C.__bases__, {
    'attribute': 42,
    'methodname1': methodname1
})
```

Python 3 makes this easier; there the sequence of parameters is treated like a function call, including support for `*` and `**` expansions:

```
class D_in_python_3(*C.__bases__, metaclass=type(C)):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you! Now i know :) Will accept answer when possible.